# SharePoint 2013: Client Object Model NavigationNode properties

Tags: 2013, navigation, properties

Can we set `NavigationNode` objects properties through Client Object Model [C#]?

Below is the server side code of what I want to achieve through Client Object Model:

```
var newNode = new SPNavigationNode("My Link", "pages/myPage.aspx");
newNode = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsFirst(newNode);
newNode.Properties.Add("NodeType", "AuthoredLinkPlain");
newNode.Properties.Add("UrlQueryString", "key=abc");
newNode.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSOM same can be coded like below code snippet.

```
            NavigationNodeCreationInformation node = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
            node.Title = "My Node";
            node.Url = "pages/default.aspx";
            NavigationNode quickLauchNode = clientContext.Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Add(node);
            quickLauchNode.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: No it doesn't help, setting the `NavigationNode` properties is what I'm looking for. Something like `NavigationNode.Properties["UrlQueryString"]="k=abc";`

Comment: This is not possible with CSOM.