# Add navigation bar heading with CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, quick-launch

How can I replicate the "Add heading" functionality of the left quick launch bar with the client side object model?

The task looks simple. Update the left bar of several sites by with a few links grouped by header like:

```
Link group 1
    Link 1
    Link 2
Link group 2
    Link 3
```

I can create the nodes and arrange them, but the "Link group x" nodes also turn into hyperlinks, even if I don't set the URL property of the NavigationNodeCreationInformation object in Sharepoint 2010, VB.

How can I either create a blank group without link?

The related part of the code (removed the actual links)

> ```
> nciHead.Title = "Group 1"
> nciHome.Title = "Homepage"
> nciHead.IsExternal = True 'otherwise it fails
> nciHome.Url = "link1"
> nd = qlColl.Add(nciHead)
> nd.Children.Add(nciHome)
> nd.Update()
> context.ExecuteQuery()
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

funny you are asking, I was just trying to do the same

in SSOM this is possible with

```
$librariesNode.Properties["BlankUrl"] = "True"
```

unfortunately, from what I have found it is NOT possible in CSOM

however this guy did it by adding

```
javascript: return true;
```

to the url field.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43fcf510-03e6-409c-85ac-84347eccb865/quick-launch-add-new-heading-without-an-url?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

more here

[SharePoint 2013: Client Object Model NavigationNode properties](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144971/sharepoint-2013-client-object-model-navigationnode-properties)

as for adding a hierarchy, here's the code (using the newly created heading node to add child nodes):

```
#heading
$libraries = new-object
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$libraries.Title = "Libraries"
$librariesNode = $ql.Add($libraries)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#link inside heading
$library = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$library.Title = $title
$library.Url = $url.ServerRelativeUrl
$library.AsLastNode = $true
$librariesNode.Children.Add($library) | Out-Null            
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```